# How do I resolve a ZenTest-4.6.2 successfully installed & missing gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.1, zentest

I'm loosely going through http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/ and am at the point of preparing to test http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/static-pages#sec:testing_tools .  I listed the autotest related gems in my Gemfile and ran `bundle install` without incident, but when I tried to start the server I got the error `Could not find ZenTest-4.6.2 in any of the sources`.  So I added ZenTest 4.6.2 to my Gemfile and reran `bundle install`.

Now according to my bash terminal, my `bundle is complete` including `Using ZenTest (4.6.2)`, but when I try to start my server I'm still getting the error `Could not find ZenTest-4.6.2 in any of the sources`.  So is it installed or is it not installed?  And how should I resolve this conflict?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should just say:    **gem "ZenTest"** in your gem file, not the version # as well.

Comment: I tried removing the version from ZenTest in the Gemfile but still got exactly the same inconsistent results, version 4.6.2 and all.  At which point, I terminated then restarted Terminal ran bundle install again, and was finally able to start up the server.  So, I'm not sure if it was removing the ZenTest version from the Gemfile or restarting Terminal that solved the problem.  And I'm even more confused about the root of the problem.  Why would removing the version fix it?  Why would restarting the Terminal fix it?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I do know that you typically don't put version numbers in (only in cases where it's a branch that you need).  For instance, for will_paginate, it could be:  gem "will_paginate", "~> 3.0.pre2".